# What should be in a first commit?

Tags: git, version-control, github, commit

I'll be starting an Android project soon to learn about Android and will be learning git alongside it.

I was curious though, what should be in the first commit? Should it be just a shell of the application? Like maybe the default files with the app info put in and such? Maybe make the class files that would be required but leaving them relatively empty?

Same questions for most projects other than this. If I'm being too vague let me know and I'll try to clarify whatever you like.

Comment: It's your preference, but I typically will just put the shell or my first "session" of work in the first commit.

Comment: I often simply put the `.gitignore` in the first commit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first commit should be some basic structure (ie. don't even fill in the structure - just commit the bare-bones). All commits should be relatively small changes. This will help you keep track of all the changes along the way (especially if you document what each small commit involved doing/changing in the commit information section). Also, you never want to commit something that is not working...

Cheers!

Comment: Small changes as in what? One piece of advice I got a while ago was to commit only working builds, which makes sense. Maybe just comment out things that don't work right if they're there.

Comment: @Portaljacker Any small changes. For instance, if i have a program with 2 bare-bone classes - after i add a constructor i would commit. After that i would fill in the constructor and then commit again. I try to do as many small-scale commits as possible to keep it clean and easy to understand. It also makes it easier to fix if you made a mistake...

Comment: @Portaljacker Also, yes, you should never commit code that doesn't work. You could comment it out - i would suggest that you get it working before you commit it though (rather than just commenting it out). This especially works if you're building this in a small team or by yourself. You can work on your code section by section (with small changes) and keep building it up. Does that make sense? Hope so.

Comment: I guess so, the spiting it into sections will be the hardest part I guess. I'm making a reddit app for android, not to make a better app, but just to learn a bunch of stuff at once.

Comment: @Portaljacker That's a pretty cool idea. Keep up the good work

Comment: Well by making I mean am planning on making. Still need to go through Hello, Android as well as Pro Git, though I wish Pro Git had example repositories like the O'Reilly Mercurial book I was looking at before I go convinced into using git. (though maybe he does stuff like that later, barely into the second chapter)

Answer (score 3):

Mostly, you just want to do it as soon as possible. You want to use source control from very beginning of your project. Just add and commit what you currently have. Directory structure and readme/source file is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, that anything you put in the first commit you will have trouble rewriting using `rebase` should you decide to later. I would put a basic README as your first commit.

Answer (score 1):

It doens't really matter, but my suggestion would be:

Commit the empty directory structure you will be using first, perhaps with a single source file and/or a build script. It is important that you commit as early as possible, so you have full history in the repository. (In other words, don't work for an hour before making the first commit).

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. If the first commit is anything other than almost empty stuff, future devs will soon attempt to find doc for code changes and arrive at the "initial commit" description for a lot o code changes. That's quite frustrating.